# Why does deactivating a plugin cause error: "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page"?

Tags: plugins, permissions, bbpress, deactivated-plugin

We recently deactivated the bbPress plugin because we don't use it anymore. Immediately following that, no admin users can get into the dashboard without hitting the infamous:

`"You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page?"`

We tried removing ALL plugins to rule out a dependance from one of those, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cookies.

Comment: I believe we tried that first but I'll double check. Any ideas as to *why* this is happening?

Comment: "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" is a generic response for when the user in question failed the capabilities check for the page that they're trying to access. Your roles/capabilities may be misconfigured in the database or some other code may be interfering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific case of bbPress, it adds new user roles and capabilities, like the "Keymaster" role. Those users who had a role that was bbPress specific won't have access to anything anymore, because after you removed the plugin, the role no longer exists.

Some users have reported that using the "User Role Editor" plugin and resetting their roles to default have fixed this issue:
http://bbpress.org/forums/topic/you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page-3/

If you have any admin that can login, he can manually reset the roles of affected users by editing their user profile and giving them the proper role on the site.

Comment: That sounds like what's going on. Any idea WHY bbPress wouldn't replace the user roles it re-writes after deactivation? Seems like a really irresponsible choice by the developers, but it's made by smart people, so maybe I'm missing something.